# Сэкономил, или не переплатил?

Tags: значение-слов

Двое покупают одну и ту же вещь. В любом ли случае можно считать, что купивший дешевле сэкономил, или могут быть разночтения?

Например: одна и та же вещь везде стоит одну цену, а в одном из магазинов стоит дороже. НЕ купив эту вещь там, а купив по обычной цене, следует ли покупателю считать, что сэкономил по отношению к купившему дороже? Или возможна ситуация при который покупатель заплативший меньше может считать, что не сэкономил, а НЕ ПЕРЕПЛАТИЛ, считая, что не сэкономил по отношению к покупателю купившему дороже?

С уважением, Сергей.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы покупаете вещь по цене, которая выше средней, то вы переплачиваете. Если вы купите ее по цене ниже средней (например, на распродаже или в интернет-магазине), то вы сэкономите часть денег. В любом случае, отсчет делается от средней цены, а не от той, которую заплатил кто-то еще.

Comment: Можно я Вам еще раз вопрос перезадам:

возможна ситуация при который покупатель заплативший меньше может считать, что не сэкономил, а НЕ ПЕРЕПЛАТИЛ, считая, что не сэкономил по отношению к покупателю купившему дороже?

Мне важно "по отношению к ....".

Comment: Можно, наверное переформулировать вопрос. 
Дано:
Два человека. Один купил по обычной цене. Другой - переплатил.
Вопрос:
Сэкономил ли не переплативший по отношению к переплатившими? Или это не совсем корректно?
Спасибо.

Comment: В принципе можно себе представить такую ситуацию. Вы с приятелем заходите в магазин, чтобы купить одну и ту же вещь, и видите, что ее цена выше средней. Тем не менее приятель покупает эту вещь, а вы решаете поискать вариант подешевле и действительно его находите. Тогда отсчет можно вести от ВАШЕГО первоначального намерения купить товар по дорогой цене, от которого вы, подумав,  отказались. Думаю, что в этом случае можно сказать, что вы сэкономили деньги, и даже сослаться на переплатившего приятеля, но это отношение будет косвенным, условным, а не прямым.

Comment: То есть с Вашей точки зрения "не переплатил" более уместная формулировка, нежели "сэкономил", при моей постановке вопроса?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Пытаюсь собрать мозги в кучу))) Мне больше нравится вторая версия - "не переплатил". Когда человек сэкономил деньги, это означает, что у него от отведенной на покупки суммы что-то осталось. А в данном случае он просто купил вещь за ее цену, следовательно, не переплатил.

Comment: Вот и я, где-то так считаю.

Но словари сообщают - "сэкономить" - сберечь, сохранить, выгадать. Отсюда следует, что заплативший меньше, за то же самое по отношению к заплатившему больше - выгадал, сиречь сэкономил. Чувствую подвох, но не могу понять в чём он)))) Ну не может человек сэкономить, покупая по фиксированной цене, даже по отношению к транжире. НЕ-МО-ЖЕТ! 

И даже такая формулировка "экономить - тратить разумно" видится мне в этом случае в чем-то не верной.

Это у меня является предметом, уже многолетнего спора, и вот не выдержав обращаюсь к профессионалам.